# version controll application/system for mysql databases

Tags: mysql, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping track of schema changes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2/keeping-track-of-schema-changes)

Hello,

How do you keep your mysql database schema under version control.

Comment: Please use proper case on title. This is not a forum or social network. Don't start the question with hello. Try to improve next questions to be more objective or at least better subjective. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 0):

[Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) is probably the most popular version control system for MySQL.  It's free and open-source.