# Comparison Tool for MySQL data base schemas

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

We'd like to update an old database schema for a new software release that requires changes in database schema (additional colums, column renames, table renames, datatypes, ...). Is there any comparison tool for MySQL data base that can help to adapt the old schema to the new one without the loss of any stored data where possible? (free software preferred)

The changes can be made by hand, yes. But we're looking for a more comfortable way and to catch all the changes made.

Comment: This is an interesting question because the second question that was ever posted in the DBA StackExchange is what you are asking now : http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2/877

Comment: I made this one for mysql table comparison https://www.tablediff.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Gate now has a MySQL Compare tool similar to their popular SQL Compare for Microsoft SQL Server.

http://mysql-compare.com/info?source=products-a-page

> The MySQL Comparison Bundle is free for non-commercial use, personal use, and for those in the charity and education sectors. 
>   source: https://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-comparison-bundle/index

Comment: I used this tool to get a visual overview over changes and diffs. It was useful in our case, but i missed a feature to rename table columns that are different. But it helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: @Jeff - Here at Redgate we've just released both our comparison tools free for non-commercial use. It would be great if you could modify your post to reflect this! Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the a very sexy answer but mysqldump & sdiff.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --no-data -h oldHost databases db1 db2 db3 > /tmp/old.sql
mysqldump -u root -p --no-data -h newHost databases db1 db2 db3 > /tmp/new.sql
sdiff /tmp/old.sql /tmp/new.sql
```

sdiff will give you a side by side comparison with differences paired w/ a > or < indicator.  I've found this to be useful in the exact scenario you describe.

The example supposes you have the new schema initialized on a different host, but this certainly isn't a requirement.  It could be a different instance (e.g. port) on the same host or the same instance with different database names.

Comment: Added ` | grep -E "(-- Table|<|>)"` on my sdiff and it works great!  Thanks for the handy one (three) liner!